# Select all checkboxes issue(jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a little issue, if i select an single checkbox and press f5 the state of the checbox will remain(so it will be checked) but if i use jQuery to select all checkboxes on a page and then press f5 all of the checkboxes will blank(so uncheck, only the one's that are handpicked will remain in there state). How can i solve this, so that when i hit refresh everything will remain the same?

the code

```
jQuery('.sellectall').click(function(){

    $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',true);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using jQuery 1.6 or later.

If so, use the  [`prop()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method instead of the [`attr()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

Then you should get the same behavior as if a user clicked the box.

```
jQuery('.sellectall').click(function(){

    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked',true);

});
```

...or set the `checked` property manually:

```
jQuery('.sellectall').click(function(){

    $('input:checkbox').each(function() { this.checked = true; });

});
```

Comment: ah, nice reason to start using prop

Comment: yes i do use 1.6, this works but it only works with 1.6+ and not with older versions, so it would be nice if it works with 1.3+.

Comment: @user759235: I updated my answer to give a solution using `.each()` that sets the property on the DOM element manually. This will work in older versions.

Comment: @lolwut: Yes, that's what my answer states. An alternate has already been provided.

Comment: @user759235: The issue is that you want to set the property instead of the attribute. The `.prop()` method ensures that the property and not the attribute is set. Otherwise you need to set the property of each element manually in the `.each()` loop.